# Make TextBox visible only if ListView is not empty (has items)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, textbox

I have a WPF TextBox which I want to make visible only if ListView has items. If ListView is empty (no items) then I want to make TextBox hidden.

Below my TextBox, note that this already have assigned an style:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"                           
         Height="20" Width="200" 
         Style="{StaticResource WatermarkedTextBox}"/>
```

I do not want to touch the existing style `WatermarkedTextBox` so I would like to do it using a BasedOn style within TextBox. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tag syntax. ListView has bool `HasItems`property. Bind TextBox `Visibility` to `ListView.HasItems` using a converter (Bool2Vis is a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` instance declared in Resources)

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         Height="20" Width="200">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource WatermarkedTextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" 
              Value="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Vis}}"/>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Great! It's working, Out of curiosity, could you confir me if this will be working with .NET 3.5?